I'm getting 401 Unauthorized when accessing protected routes using http only cookies in Laravel with axios
I'm working on a Laravel application with JWT authentication, and I'm trying to use http-only cookies for authentication. Despite setting the cookie correctly on login, I'm still receiving a 401 Unauthorized error when accessing protected routes using axios. Here's my setup
$token = JWTAuth::claims($claims)->fromUser($user);
$cookie = Cookie::make('auth_token', $token, 60, null, null, false, true, false, 'Strict');

if ($user->status == 'active' && $user->is_verified == 1) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'User logged in successfully',
        'token' => $token,
        'user' => UserService::data($user->id)
    ], 200)->withCookie($cookie)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
}


Axios Configuration
public async apiRequest(endpoints: { [key: string]: Record<any, any> }, method: string = 'POST'): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> {
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
        const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
            baseURL: this.url,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            },
            timeout: 40000,
        });

        const payload: { [key: string]: string } = {};

        for (const [endpoint, data] of Object.entries(endpoints)) {
            const pre= `__${endpoint}`;
            payload[pre] = encryptData(data);
        }

        try {
            const response: AxiosResponse<ApiResponse> = await axiosInstance.request({
                url: '/request.json',
                method: method,
                data: JSON.stringify(payload)
            });

            return response;

        } catch (error: any) {
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response?.status === 401) {
                this.logout();
            }
            console.error('Error making request:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

My Middleware
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function ($router) {
    Route::match(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'], 'action.json', [RequestController::class, 'handle']);
    Route::post('/request.json', [ApiController::class, 'handle']);
});

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'signup', 'password/reset', 'reset', 'test', 'getUser']]);
    }

Even with these setup, I still receive a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to access protected routes.
How can I resolve the 401 Unauthorized error and ensure that my http-only cookies are properly recognized for authentication in Laravel?
Here's what I tried:

Ensured that supports_credentials is set to true and the correct origin is allowed.
Set withCredentials: true in the axios request.
Verified that the routes are protected with the correct middleware.

I wanted to be able to make api calls to the server without having to save the token on the client.

Are you getting any CORS-related errors in the browser console?

Yes, I think Content-Type not allowed in allowed origin or something like that, I've forgotten. I've resolved in storing the token on the client side instead of using cookie.

Probably rather, X-Requested-With not allowed? You explicitly allowed Content-Type and Authorization as additional headers outside of the range of "CORS save" headers, but not that one ...

Are you tried to create request via postman, you're sure that laravel working well?
Then problem could be with JS side

Hi! If you need clarification or further information from the individual who created the question, please ask those in the comment section, and then proceed with posting an answer when you have an actual answer :)

Yes, it does work with postman. The problem is, I am using http-only cookie, and the browser doesn't seem to include it when making request to the server.
